# What's the best way to amend a url via javascript?

Tags: javascript

My wordpress site has a search form that is crap.

It produces this search string: `www.mysite.com/properties/?wpp_search[sort_order]=DESC&wpp_search[sort_by]=price&wpp_search[pagination]=on&wpp_search[per_page]=10&wpp_search[strict_search]=false&wpp_search[property_type]=residential_sales%2Cresidential_lettings%2Ccommercial%2Cfine_living&wpp_search[area]=&wpp_search[price][min]=&wpp_search[price][max]=&wpp_search[branch]=-1&wpp_search[bedrooms]=-1&wpp_search[department]=-1#propertycontent`

What's the best way to grab this string, and change certain aspects eg:
`[sort_order]=ASC`
`[sort_by]=price`

Then reload the page displaying the new string and thus changing the form output?

Comment: A mix of deserialising your string and then using `location.href` should work. Try something like `data = location.href.split('?')[1].split('&').map(a => a.split('='))`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
url.replace('[sort_order]=DESC','[sort_order]=ASC').replace('[sort_by]=price','[sort_by]=newPrice');
```

Comment: Cool. Will this only replace the named variables? Then I just force a reload of the page, or do I have to do something else?

Comment: @GT22 It just gives you the expected URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the url's query portion using [`location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/search). Look for the parameter, modify, reconstruct your url and assign that value to [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location#Example_1_Navigate_to_a_new_page) to load the page with that url.